# Disabling SiteEdit(XPM) only for specific CT on DD4T Java

Tags: experience-manager, dd4t

I'm using DD4T Java version 2 and enabling SiteEdit(Experience Manager).
By configuring siteeditsettings.xml, div tag and HTML comment "Start Component Presentation" are generated automatically for all component presentation.

But I have some CT that I don't want to enable SiteEdit. Is it possible to exclude specific CT from enabling SiteEdit?

(For instance, on Compound Template, it's possible by removing "Enable inline editing for content" TBB from CT.)

Regards,

**Workaround**

The component template which generates meta tag is assigned to region "Meta".
I Wrote following code in page template JSP, then SiteEdit tag is not generated.

```
<c:forEach var="renderedComponent" items="${ContentModel.getRenderedComponents().get('Meta')}">
<c:set var="meta" value="${renderedComponent.getCp().getComponent()}"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="${Here's code to output value of component}" />
<meta name="description" content="${Here's code to output value of component)}" />
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you finally find a solution for not to generate a div tag in the head tag? Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

You can disable Experience Manager by opening the Component Template in question and unselecting the check box that states "Enable for inline editing". This will still generate the markup (that's controlled by the Template code), but editors will not be allowed to edit anything generated by that template.

Comment: One of my component templates outputs rendered content into head tag(it generates meta tag). The problem is that div tag is generated in head tag, if XPM is enabled.Is there any way not to generate div tag or to generate different tag? Is customizing DD4T source code required to do that?

Comment: I made work around that generates meta tag by PT, not by CT. I added comment and source code.